# Thing that opposes its origin

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for **the thing** or **phenomenon** that opposes its origin like in **Lenz's Law** which states that:

> If an induced current flows, its direction is always such that it will oppose the change which produced it. [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law)

So, if a magnetic field generated in response of another magnetic field opposes the field it is caused by, it opposes its origin.

Another general example I can think of is when we tie up two ropes together. Now, to separate them if we pull them apart; it makes the tie stronger. We wanted to separate them but instead made the tie more stronger.

Comment: Are there any other examples besides magnetic fields? If it's not a general phenomenon, there's not much need for a general word for it.

Comment: yes!! another general example I can think of is when we tie up 2 ropes togather. Now to seprate them if we pull them apart it makes the tie more stronger. We wanted to seprate them but instead made the tie more stronger

Comment: That seems like a stretch to consider that to be like a magnetic field. You're describing something that has the opposite effect from what you expect.

Comment: I would call that one with the ropes a **paradox** :-) although I don't think it would fit other uses...

Comment: Maybe the word you're looking for is _reciprocal_?

Comment: Or, if you are looking for a non-scientific term, one might say that your plan to untie the ropes **backfired**, although that might be a bit strong.

Comment: It seems the OP's question and his follow-up edit have a generated the effect that it is asking us to describe :-) The first two examples are clearly *action/reaction* dynamics as described by Newton's Third Law (and *Le Châtelier's principle* is simply a manifestation of that law in the field of chemistry). The third example is simply a natural consequence of **pulling** the rope instead of **pushing** it.

Comment: How about [*anti-genesis*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=IA-_po38YB0C&pg=PA34&dq=%22anti-genesis%22+origin&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YD9EVfKaLNCwyATYwIEI&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22anti-genesis%22%20origin&f=false) ?

Comment: @ermanen you just redefined what I have defined

Comment: @Ahmad: It is not "redefining". It is a word that can be used. It actually means "against origin" but the word is not that common. There are many common words given but they don't exactly fit your criteria.

Comment: Some other terms that might be of use: Auto-inverted, Counteracted, Contraverted, Self-Cancellation, Reverse feedback.

Answer (score 9):

*[Recoil](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recoil)*:

> verb
>
> (recoil on/upon) (Of an action) have an adverse reactive effect on
>   (the originator):
>
> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN]   The action of recoiling:
>
> *oxforddictionaries.com*

Answer (score 5):

This is essentially negative feedback, as propounded in **Le Châtelier's principle**

From [Infoplease](http://www.infoplease.com/encyclopedia/science/le-chatelier-principle.html):

> Le Châtelier's principle is [in the first analysis] a chemical
>   principle that states that if a system in equilibrium is disturbed by
>   changes in determining factors, such as temperature, pressure, and
>   concentration of components, the system will tend to shift its
>   equilibrium position so as to counteract the effect of the
>   disturbance.

Though originally envisioned only as an effect in chemistry, it has been seen to apply analogously in other scientific fields:

> The more general form of the principle applies to other disciplines.
>   Homeostasis and Lenz's law are examples. [[About Education](http://chemistry.about.com/od/chemicalreactions/a/le-chateliers-principle.htm)]

and even in equilibrium systems in economics [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle)].

The most general form of the effect (from Wikipedia) is

> Any change in status quo prompts an opposing reaction in the
>   responding system.

Comment: I like both the negative feedback and Le Chatelier-Brown principle, but I think that it is important to emphasize that these are not the same thing. Negative feedback includes a loop, and LCB principle is more of a left-to-right (or right-to-left) process. The difference is pointed out in [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3059932/) example. Basically, in negative feedback an effect counters its own intensity by countering the process that is giving it rise; in LCBP the equilibrium shifts to counter the effect of a process, it doesn't counter the initial process itself.

Comment: P.S. Physics isn't my field so I'm not sure which of these terms would apply for the Lenz's law. But that isn't an EL&U question.

Comment: you are right @Lucky Negative Feedback is not the same thing. I'm talking about the thing let's say B caused by let's say A which counters A

Comment: Problem with word Feedback is that in Science its not cause by the 1st Function rather its already there to oppose upcoming 1st Function & its not a general word. More of a **Scientific Term**

Answer (score 5):

*[Backlash](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/backlash)*:

> n.
>
> 1. A sudden or violent backward whipping motion.
> 2. An antagonistic reaction to a trend, development, or event:
>    *"As the backlash against divorce progressed, state legislatures ... called for
>    a rollback of no-fault divorce laws and even for premarital waiting
>    periods" (Walter Kirn).*
> 3. A snarl formed in the part of a fishing line that is wound around the reel.
> 4. The play resulting from loose connections between gears or other mechanical elements.

*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition.*

Comment: Its not the same thing as **Backlash** is completely equal to **Reaction**. So it doesn't always counter the 1st thing it just happens in reaction of the 1st process like When you fire a bullet its **Reaction** or **Recoil**

Answer (score 5):

*[Kick](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kick)* or *[kickback](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kickback)*:

> ***kick***
>
> noun
>
> 2.1 The recoil of a gun when discharged.
>
> ***kickback***
>
> noun
>
> 1 A sudden forceful recoil:
>
> *ODO*

Answer (score 5):

*[Counteraction](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/counteract?q=counteraction#counteract__9)*, if you are looking for something more "defiant" than *reaction*:

> noun
>
> An action ***against*** (something) in order to reduce its force or
>   neutralize it:
>
> *ODO **Emphasis** mine*

Answer (score 4):

Commonly referred to as *[Newton's Third Law](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/newtlaws/Lesson-4/Newton-s-Third-Law)*:

> These two forces are called ***action*** and ***reaction*** forces and are the subject of Newton's third law of motion. Formally stated, Newton's third law is:
>
> For every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction.
>
> *physicsclassroom.com*

The opposing force is called *[reaction](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reaction)*:

> 3 [MASS NOUN] Physics A force exerted in opposition to an applied force:
>
> *oxforddictionaries.com*

Comment: Again I'm not looking for a **Scientific Term** as **reaction** in general doesn't always defy its origin. Its mostly is there in reaction to the 1st phenomena.

Comment: Applying a constraint to a system in say chemistry gives rise to an attenuating, not a totally negating, counter-effect.